# How do I load a csv file into actian table?

Tags: vectorwise, actian

The "copy" command is successful, but junk data is loaded into the table.
"vwload" command errors out with a message "No table name specified".
How do I load a csv file into actian table?

```
*  COPY TABLE airport2 () FROM '/tmp/head.csv' \g

* select * from airport2\g
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
(1 row)
continue

$ /opt/Actian/VectorVW/ingres/bin/vwload –f "," –q "\"" –s 1 –l t1.log –t airport1 test /tmp/head.csv
No table name specified
Usage: vwload [options] database file ...
Try vwload --help
```

Update

This copy command does not complete. It shows "Excuting..." but there is no response after that, I have to kill the session.

```
$ /opt/Actian/VectorVW/ingres/bin/sql test

continue
* copy table airport2 (
* m1 = char(0) comma,
* d1 = char(0) comma,
* s1 = char(0) comma,
* m2 = char(0) comma,
* m3 = char(0) comma,
* sent_date = char(0) comma,
* stat = char(0) comma,
* done_date = char(0) comma,
* params_err = char(0) nl)
* from /tmp/head.csv \g
Executing . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an 'actian table'.  Action is a company which has bought several databases. (https://www.actian.com/product-overview/)

Unfortunately they do no make things easy, but you seem to be using 'ACtian X' (https://www.actian.com/data-management/actian-x-hybrid-rdbms/), or an older version of that.

The documentation is one thing they have!, It's available online, search their website ...